# How to merge a $1$-cycle with an $n$-cycle

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

I know that $(14625)$ is equal to $(14)(23)(36)(53)(54)$. I want to know how to get from one to the other algebraically - in other words how to 'absorb' $(3)$ into $(14625)$. The best I have managed is:

$$(14625)(3)$$
$$=(14)(4625)(3)$$
$$=(14)(6254)(3)$$
$$=(14)(625)(54)(3)$$
$$=(14)(256)(54)(3)$$
$$=(14)(56)(26)(54)(3)$$
$$=(14)(56)(26)(54)(36)(63)$$
$$=(14)(56)(26)(36)(63)(54)$$
$$=(14)(33256)(54)$$
$$=(14)(3256)(54)$$
$$=(14)(2563)(54)$$
$$=(14)(36)(53)(23)(54)$$

which is not correct. (The transpositions are correct but they are in the wrong order). I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: In cycle notation, $(33256)$ doesn't make sense: an element can appear in a cycle only once. It appears that your mistake is there, because on the line before it you have $6 \mapsto 2$, like in the original permutation, while after that line $6 \mapsto 3$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, my reasoning in that step was that (ad)(bd)(cd) = (cbad), so (56)(26)(36)(63) = (56)(26)(36)(36) = (33256). I then simplified (33256) = (3256), thinking 'Well, going from 3 to 3 is the same as doing nothing, so I can just get rid of one of those 3's'. Is that not right? Can you suggest an alternative method to get from (14625)(3) to (14)(23)(36)(53)(54)?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> my reasoning in that step was that $(ad)(bd)(cd) = (cbad)$, so $(56)(26)(36)(63) = (56)(26)(36)(36) = (33256)$.

This rule only works when $a, b, c, d$ are all different, as you can see.

> Can you suggest an alternative method to get from $(14625)(3)$ to $(14)(23)(36)(53)(54)$?

One failsafe way is to write
$$
(14625) = (14)(14)(14625) = (14)(23)(23)(14)(14625) = ... = (14)(23)(36)(53)(54)(54)(53)(36)(23)(14)(14625),
$$
and then just multiply all the terms on the right until they all cancel.